# Should I take the weather into account when I replace guitar strings?

Tags: guitar, maintenance, strings

I have been told that the strings in a guitar should be replaced at least every six months (I know this can be subjective).

I have a classical guitar which has been several years with the same strings, and plan to replace them.

My question is if it matters the kind of weather/temperature of the day (hot or cold), when replacing the strings, like for instance affecting the tension, or not settling as fast as with a different temperature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really, good strings will sound good at any (reasonable) temperature. If you go outside with the guitar (where it's cold), you might need to tune it again, because the temperature affects the tension of the strings.

You might also need to adjust your neck, depending on the moisture level (this is typically done twice a year) to maintain proper string action.